# How to keep leading zeros by transforming array to single numbers

Tags: matlab

So my problem was, when i'm trying to combine number from different columns, leading zeros disappear, here's my code:

```
Bthree= [0  0   1
9   1   2
0   5   7]


len=size(Bthree);
    A=[];
    for jj=1:len(1)
        s=int2str(Bthree(jj,1:3));
        s=s(s~=' ');
        A(jj,:)=[str2num(s)];
    end
```

Output

```
1
912
57
```

as you can see leading zeros disappear but i want zero to be keep

desired output:

```
001
912
057
```

so can i do that? thanks

Comment: Do you want to store it with leading zeros, or just have it displayed with leading zeros?

Comment: Are they always single digit numbers in `Bthree` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep leading zeros you likely **need to store your data as strings:**

```
Bcell = strrep(cellstr(num2str(Bthree)),' ','')
```

returns a cell array of strings our your numbers. For a char array additional do:

```
Bchar = cell2mat(Bcell)
```

Or alternatively you can get the char array directly by:

```
Bchar = reshape(sprintf('%i',Bthree),size(Bthree))
```

returning:

```
Bcell = 

    '001'
    '912'
    '057'


Bchar =

001
912
057
```

---

As you seem to be not sure if you really need the leading zeros, here a short way for the conversion to doubles:

```
Bdouble = str2num(Bchar)

Bdouble =

     1
   912
    57
```

Comment: how about you have m x n array? is it still applicable?

Comment: @Raldernors in my understanding `Bthree` is already an m x n array (though m = n), it works for any m and n.

Comment: the output is char cell, how can you convert it into number cell where zero don't disappear?

Comment: @Raldenors it's not possible. What number exists with leading zeros? For what purpose? You should ask a new question with a little wider context, so we can help you with your problem. But apart from binary numbers, *normal* numbers can't be stored as numbers (numerical) with leading zeros.

Comment: basically i want it to be involve in mathematical operation and you can't add or minus char  cell or string cell to number cell

Comment: @Raldenors, of course not, but **what do you need the leading zeros for then?**

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `int2str` with `num2str`.

Then your code should look like:

```
Bthree= [0  0   1;9   1   2;0   5   7];

A=[];
for jj=1:size(Bthree,1)
    s=num2str(Bthree(jj,1:3));
    A(jj,:)=[str2num(s)];
end
```