# How to combine numbers and add up numbers in different column

Tags: matlab, matrix

This is continuation of my previous questions ([**one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717837/how-to-count-characters-or-unique-string-in-matlab), [**two**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716474/how-to-keep-leading-zeros-by-transforming-array-to-single-numbers)) and this is my real problem
I have an array of data:

```
a   b   c   d
0   1   2   5
0   1   7   1
0   0   5   5
0   0   0   1
0   1   0   2
```

as you can see i want abc to be combine and in one column, just like this:

```
abc    d
012    5
017    1
005    5
000    1
010    2
```

so i will now have 2 columns abc and d

next i want to count repeated values of d, add it up and combined those corresponding abc, see below

```
abc        d
012,005    10
017,010    2
010        5
```

so as you can see, 012, and 005 combine because they have the same value of d, and their d add up so it become 10, so how i can do that? this is my real problem please help thanks.

Comment: Please be specific with your data structures! Your last question was not perfectly clear. Are `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` variable names or are they entries in the  cell-array? Are your numbers given as numerics, strings, cell arrays of numerics or char arrays?

Comment: You will draw more attention to this question if it came up with matlab code. i.e. ``a = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0]; b = [1; 1; 0; 0; 1];`` ... Also: are your vector elements strings or numbers? What datatype should ``abc`` be? a vector of cell-arrays?

Comment: they're number cell ,sir

Comment: a,b,c, and,d  are just representation of columns, no need to include those letters

Comment: @Raldenors: Please look into the difference [*numeric array*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-numeric-arrays.html) vs [*cell array containing numerics*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) in Matlab. Those are quite different! People will have problems answering your questions if you confuse those!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A = [...
0   1   2   5;
0   1   7   1;
0   0   5   5;
0   0   0   1;
0   1   0   2 ]

%// column for identification
subs = A(:,4);
%// get order for sorting output
order = unique(subs,'stable')

%// get strings from numbers
abc = cellstr(reshape(sprintf('%i',A(:,1:3)),size(A(:,1:3))))

%// gather abc
groups = accumarray(subs,1:numel(subs),[],@(x) {abc(x)})

%// sum counts
counts = accumarray(subs,subs,[],@sum)

%// output
out = [groups num2cell(counts)]

%// reorder output
out = out(order,:)

%// filter output
out(find(~counts(order)),:) = []
```

---

```
out = 

    {2x1 cell}    [10]
    {2x1 cell}    [ 2]
    {1x1 cell}    [ 2]
```

with for example

```
out{1,1} = 

'005'
'012'
```

As you see `out{1,1}` is still not in the correct order. The reason is that [**`accumarray` is not stable**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463433/stable-accumarray-in-matlab). To solve it, use the function `accumarrayStable` provided in the link:

```
function A = accumarrayStable(subs, val, varargin)
[subs(:,end:-1:1), I] = sortrows(subs(:,end:-1:1));
A = accumarray(subs, val(I), varargin{:});
end
```

and you will finally get:

```
out{1,1} =

    '012'
    '005'
```

Comment: ahm it appears that the output become 5x2 instead of 3x2, is there away to delete those rows with no values? thanks

Comment: and also the order was reverse, the combination 017,005, was located at the bottom instead at the top.

Comment: what could be the possible  reason why i get an error: Error using accumarray
First input SUBS must contain positive integer subscripts.

Comment: @Raldenors it depends on your input array. Is it exactly how you posted it? does it just contain positive integers? does it contain also zeros in the 4th column?

Comment: my data array is just like what i posted, it contains only positive, and there is no zero in 4th column just like what i posted

Comment: @Raldenors What happens if you copy&paste just my code. Does it work? `clear` your workspace before

Comment: yea it works, where i can place the:  function A = accumarrayStable(subs, val, varargin)
[subs(:,end:-1:1), I] = sortrows(subs(:,end:-1:1));
A = accumarray(subs, val(I), varargin{:});
end

Comment: @Raldenors either an extra function file or, in case your script is also a function, under your main function.

Comment: is there another way to display "012,005"? in the column? because it appears that it is on another column array, because i want to print that data

Comment: @Raldenors this is again another question. Include a minimal example there and be clear what you mean with "print". But not here in the comments, it's not a forum or chat.

Comment: i mean print is to be printed in printer. whenever i copy the the data and paste into word there is no "012,005" appear, and also check my desired output

Comment: @Raldenors, well seriously, I'm not a code writing service. Ask a new question. You never mentioned before that you want to print it out with a printer. This is a completely different issue. And your desired output is not possible, so I assumed it to be schematic. Be more clear please the next time. But in any way it would be a new question.

Comment: `accumarray`! `accumarray`! `accumarray`!